# combine django-filter with an ajax call

Tags: django, ajax, django-filter

I am using a package called django-filter  it's basically a filtering system  but i want to improve it and filter my   product model without refreshing the page

filter.py

```
class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

category = django_filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(field_name='category', choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
Type = django_filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(field_name='Type', choices=TYPE_CHOICES, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())

class Meta:
     model = Product
     fields = {
        'price': ['lt', 'gt'],

    }
```

views.py :

```
def ProductList(request):
products = Product.objects.all()
f        = ProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=products)
context={
    'products' :products,
    'filter'   :f,
}

return render(request,'ProductList.html',context)
```

the filtering form  is automatically generated with the template tag **filter.form** , when the form is submitted the product model is filtered based on the parameters  inside the request.Get
but if i prevent the form submission to make an Ajax request  that  **request.GET** does not exist
so how do i send that same data inside an ajax request ??

Comment: You need to either make a separate endpoint for the Json response or respect the content type header and change your response type based on it. Look into Django rest framework if this could be something you do often

Comment: @bryan60 well that's he problem i don't know anything about django rest framework or ajax  lol

Comment: well, this question is a little overly broad for SO tbh, I'd do some research, follow the DRF tutorials and the django tutorials (I believe they do address something like this use case but i could be mistaken), and come back here when you run into specific problems with implementation

Comment: @bryan60 yes  it looks like i have to use  djange rest framework , i will  give it a try